# credit card check validation c++

Tags: c++

Question - In C++

Credit Card Number Check, The last digit of a credit card number is the check digit, which protects against transcription errors such as an error in a single digit or switching two digits. The following method is used to verify actual credit card numbers but, for simplicity, we will describe it for numbers with 8 digits instead of 16:

• Starting from the rightmost digit, form the sum of every other digit. For example, if the credit card number is 43589795, then you form the sum: 5 + 7 + 8 + 3 = 23.

• Double each of the digits that were not included in the preceding step. Add all digits of the resulting numbers. For example, with the number given above, doubling the digits, starting with the next-to-last one, yields: 18 18 10 8. Adding all digits in these values yields: 1 + 8 + 1 + 8 + 1 + 0 + 8 = 27.

• Add the sums of the two preceding steps. If the last digit of the result is 0, the number is valid. In our case, 23 + 27 = 50, so the number is valid.

Write a program that implements this algorithmn and prints whether the number is valid or not.

**This is what I have so far**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum_even = 0;
    string oddnum;
    string oddnum_temp;
    cout << "Enter an 8 digit card credit card number: " << endl;
    string number;
    cin >> number;

int length  =  number.length();

if (length != 8)
{
    cout <<"Invalid credit card number: " <<endl;
}


for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    if (i%2 == 0)
    {
        sum_even = number.substr(i, 1); 
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            if (j%2 == 1)
            {
                oddnum =  number.substr(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    oddnum_temp =  oddnum.substr(i, 8);

}

cout << oddnum_temp << endl;
```

**Is my approach right? How do I move forward because I get a Core Dumped error**

Comment: Your problem will not have anything to do with credit card numbers, but be about a memory handling problem. Look at the title, and your example code, under that light... should you perhaps have asked / prepared this a bit differently?

Comment: If you get a segmentation fault then you have a crash because you do something bad you should not be doing. You need to learn how to use a debugger, then you can run your program in the debugger and catch the crash "in action" and see where it happens. You will also be able to see and walk up the function call stack, so you can go to your code (if the debugger haven't stopped there already) and then you can examine values of variables, all to help you locate and hopefully understand why the crash happens. At the very least please tell us where the crash happens in *your* code.

Comment: Characters indices in strings are zero-based in C++ (just like everything else). The `for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)` is probably the problem since there is no character available at index `8`.

Comment: One thing you should look at though, is that string indexes in C++ start with *zero* and go up to the size minus one. Also, how do you expect to get an 8-character substring from an 8-character string when starting from anything but the first character?

Comment: Finally, if you read a string, then you have *characters* and not numbers in that string. Characters have different encodings, but with the most common [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) the value for the *character* `'1'` is not `1` but `49`.

Answer (score 1):

Saul,
   You need to run your code through a debugger a bit more before worrying about the check digit.  You are missing some basic concepts and here are the things I noticed. 
   On the surface your j var never increments. (do some research on for loops, variable scoping and incrementing) 

You are trying to walk the string oddnum without using the length of oddnum, and moving past the memory owned by the string. (do some research on string manipulation)
 

Strings and all other arrays in c++ are zero based, you are counting from 1 and always missing the first element in your string. (research on array accessing)

You need to remember that you are storing your numbers in a string.  This means you have to take each element in the string and convert the value of the character to a number (research a bit on casting in c++).

 There are likely a few more things you need to clean up.  But you seriously will be able to catch your errors best with a few break points in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code It will work exactly same as you wanted

```
//Credit card no validation
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>                        //for getche()
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int no1=0,od=0,to=0,fi=0;
    int j=(-1),ev=0,odd=0;
    int i=1;
    int max=15;
    int x[max];
    char ch='a';
    string cardno;
    cout<<"Enter the 8 digit card no";
          do
            {
              ch=getche();
              x[i] = ch-48;                //-48 because of ASCII valuse
              ++i;
              ++j;
            }while(ch != '\r');

            if(j!=8)
            {
                cout<<"\nCredit card is INVALID";
                exit(0);
            }

      cout<<endl;
      for(int j=1;j<5;j++)
      ev+=x[2*j];
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
      {
          od=2*x[(2*j)+1];
          no1=od%10+od/10;
          odd+=no1;
      }
   cout<<"Total no of DIGITS in CARD is:"<<j<<endl;
   cout<<"Sum of odd digit is "<<ev<<endl;
   cout<<"Sum of even digit is "<<odd<<endl;
   to=ev+odd;
   fi=to%10;
   if(fi==0)
   {
     cout<<"CREDIT CARD IS VALID";
   }
   if(fi!=0)
   {
     cout<<"Credit card is INVALID";
   }

   return 0;
```

it should be helpfull i guess

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you are iterating from 1 to 8 (8 included). So, when your code reaches

```
if (i%2 == 0)
{
    sum_even = number.substr(i, 1); 
}
```

It will try to create a substring from out of the string bounds

Answer (score 0):

try this it would be helpful

but the program is in java language so understand the approach to solve this question and use it in your solution

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Creditcard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int sum1 = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter 8 digit credit card number :");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String string = kb.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                char ch = (string.charAt(i));
                int no = ch - 48;
                sum = sum + no;
            }

            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                char ch1 = (string.charAt(i));
                int no1 = ch1 - 48;
                no1 = (2 * no1);
                while (no1 != 0) {
                    int temp1 = no1 % 10;
                    no1 = no1 / 10;
                    sum1 = sum1 + temp1;
                }

            }

        }
        int result = sum + sum1;
        if (result % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println("valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }

    }
}
```